# I am trying to get pivot table in jupyter notebook but aggfunc not working

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to get pivot table in jupyter notebook but aggfunc=sum is not working.
I am getting all data side by side not as summation.Below is the full code:

```
Sales_pivot = pd.pivot_table(Sales_Info,  index=["Sub- Hub"], values="Net Sales In Pricing Currency (USD)",aggfunc=sum)
Sales_pivot.head()
```

Comment: Hi Nisha, please provide an example of the data you are using and the output you are getting. This makes it easier to answer your question.

Comment: Also useful should be the structure of `Sales_Info`